# menu icon image is not coming

Tags: 7

I am using drupal7 with menu icon module. I added a image on Home menu. but this is not showing. 
Here is my [link](http://pickandpurchase.com/portal/)

I am unable to rectify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS in style.css line 432 is overwriting the CSS that the module is trying to use. You should probably comment that CSS out or edit/remove it's background property.

Comment: No, Still it is not working. this is path url("/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/menu_icons/menu_icon_218.gif") but when i use this path url("/portal/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/menu_icons/menu_icon_218.gif") it is working..

Comment: I visited your site - I see it working now.

Comment: no. i added static code in module file. which is not a good ide